# Why is (327.59 * 100.0) < 32759.0 true?

Tags: f#, floating-point

Multiplying

```
(327.59 * 100.0)
```

produces a number less than 32759, why is that? And how can this be avoided?

Comment: It's how floating point value works. To avoid this use `decimal`

Comment: `double` is fundamentally a binary number. Because of this is it can't represent `327.59` exactly instead you get something that is close to it. As @Petr said, use `decimal` to avoid this. `decimal` uses base 10 therefore `327.59` can be represented exactly. FYI; Kahan recommended Intel to use decimal for floating points in the 70's. It was too late to change and 40 years later we are paying the price over and over again

Comment: Read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a modified pretty printer for the F# Interactive the numeric precision is shown fully.

```
fsi.AddPrinter( fun (x:float) -> sprintf "%26.16e" x)

(327.59 * 100.0)
// val it : float =    3.2758999999999996e+004

32759.0
// val it : float =    3.2759000000000000e+004
```

That's why

```
(327.59 * 100.0) < 32759.0 = true
```

Comment: thank you, printf "%f" was hiding it